# unable to query with friendly_id rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my controller

```
before_action :seo_url_product,only: :product

def seo_url_product
    if params[:id]
         @posts = Post.friendly.where(sub_category_id: params[:id]).paginate(page:   params[:page], per_page: 2).to_a
     end
end
```

Here is my view

```
<% category.sub_categories.each do |sub_category| %>
    <li><%= link_to sub_category.name, controller: :posts, action: :product, id: sub_category %></li>
<% end %>
```

I can see friendly url when i click sub_categories but i could not see any result.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are trying to query with `slug` not the real id. As you know friendly_id use slug. So you should find the real id first then try to query.

Insted of `params[:id]` in `where` query you can use the following.

```
sub_category_id = Sub_category.friendly.find(params[:id]) # This find id insted of slug
@posts = Post.friendly.where(sub_category_id: sub_category_id).paginate(page:   params[:page], per_page: 2).to_a
```